# OpenVPN with several servers

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-12.04

We have our servers spread over 3 different sites (geographically). So, we have deployed a VPN using OpenVPN so that machines (virtual or not) can communicate to each others, and sysadmins can access any machine. Each site has one (or two) own subnet(s) /24 on the VPN addresses pool. So, far all the clients connect to the same OpenVPN server on a specific machine on a specific site. This is a SPOF and we would like to avoid it.

Reading OpenVPN shows that it is possible to load balance OpenVPN, the whole point is that in such case, clients connect randomly to a server and then, don't see each others.

The whole point here would be to have one server per site, clients connecting to their closest server. And then, to interconnect all the sites together, so that client can see any other client, whatever its site.

Our whole infrastructure is using Ubuntu 12.04LTS and thus OpenVPN 2.2.

If unclear, or imprecise, I can provide more details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sooo, what is the question?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Basically, it is how to ensure that the 3 OpenVPN can communicate together? Share their clients? Act like it is a single network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just  bridge those openvpn servers using "internal" network of openvpns :) Then you would have internal network so the clients can talk to each another.

Comment: And how to do so?

Comment: Just make 3 P2P openvpn connections and bridge them. Be sure to enable STP to avoid loops.